# Как отключить Cloudflare для некоторых страниц сайта?

Tags: видео, https, кэширование, dns

В общем весь вопрос в названии. Хочу отключить пропускание трафика через Cloudflare для части страниц сайта для того чтобы видео не гонялись через Cloudflare. Потому что он их тормозит и сам Cloudflare от такого не в восторге. На сайте стоит Let's encrypt сертификат. Вот идея в том чтобы видео не через cloudflare шли, а страницы через Cloudflare.

Comment: Завести отдельный домен. Типа `video.mysite.ru`.

Comment: А может посмотреть на их видео стриминг https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/products/cloudflare-stream/ или вообще переложить видео куда-нибудь в амазон

Comment: @AlexeyTen Только так можно? Думал что как-то можно настроить исключение папки да и все, странно почему не сделали они? Или все-же есть такая настройка?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, спс. про их ручеек  вкурсе и про Амазон тоже.

Comment: Посмотрите как устроен протокол http. Сначала подключаемся к домену, потом говорим что именно хотим скачать, но к этому моменту мы уже подключились к серверу